# "undefined is not an object" this.state not getting bound

Tags: reactjs, react-native

My react-native component, which I'm creating via `React.createClass`, does not seem to be binding the `this` keyword correctly, preventing me from accessing `this.state`.  Here's the error I get:

[image: error]

And the code is below.  I don't see anything essentially different from the examples on the website, so I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  How can I fix this?

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');

var Main = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: () => {
    return { username: '', isloading: false, iserror: false };
  },
  handleChange: (event) => {
    this.setState({
      username: event.nativeEvent.text
    });
  },
  handleSubmit: (event) => {
    this.setState({
      isloading: true
    });
    console.log('Submitting... ' + this.state.username);
  },
  render: () => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
        <Text> Search for a Github User</Text>
        <TextInput style={styles.searchInput}
                   value={this.state.username}
                   onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} /> 
        <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button}
                            underlayColor='white'
                            onPress={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)} /> 
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}> SEARCH</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
});

var { Text, View, StyleSheet, TextInput, TouchableHighlight, ActivityIndicatorIOS } = React;

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mainContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 30,
    marginTop: 65,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#48BBEC'
  },
  title: {
    marginBottom: 20,
    fontSize: 25,
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#fff'
  },
  searchInput: {
    height: 50,
    padding: 4,
    marginRight: 5,
    fontSize: 23,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 8,
    color: 'white'
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize: 18,
    color: '#111',
    alignSelf: 'center'
  },
  button: {
    height: 45,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderColor: 'white',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 8,
    marginBottom: 10,
    marginTop: 10,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
});

module.exports = Main
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is the use of the ES6 fat arrow in `render: () => {` that will cause the autobind features that React supplies in the `.createClass` function not to work.

Simply changing this to `render: function() {..` should do the trick if you don't want to convert your code to ES6 classes.

If you do convert it to ES6 classes, take a look at [this](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#no-autobinding)

> Methods follow the same semantics as regular ES6 classes, meaning that
>   they don't automatically bind this to the instance. You'll have to
>   explicitly use .bind(this) or arrow functions =>.

Comment: Thanks. The reference url helped me greatly too!