# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'state.cameraType')

Tags: javascript, binding, react-native, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to get a React Native app set up following [this](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/09/use-the-ios-camera-in-your-react-native-mobile-app/) post and then ported over to ES6. Here's the main page code:

```
"use strict";
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Camera from 'react-native-camera';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  TouchableHighlight,
} from 'react-native';

export default class AwesomeProject extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {cameraType: Camera.constants.Type.back};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Camera
        ref="cam"
        style={styles.container}
        type={this.state.cameraType}>
        <View style={styles.buttonBar}>
          <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} onPress={this._switchCamera.bind(this)}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Flip</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
          <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} onPress={this._takePicture.bind(this)}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Take</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
      </Camera>
    );
  }

  _switchCamera: () => {
    var state = this.state;
    console.log(this.state);
    state.cameraType = state.cameraType === Camera.constants.Type.back ? Camera.constants.Type.front : Camera.constants.Type.back;
    this.setState(state);
  }

  _takePicture: () => {
    console.log(this.refs);
    this.refs.cam.capture(function(err, data) {
      console.log(err, data);
    });
  }

};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
  },
  buttonBar: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    position: "absolute",
    bottom: 25,
    right: 0,
    left: 0,
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  button: {
    padding: 10,
    color: "#FFFFFF",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "#FFFFFF",
    margin: 5
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: "#FFFFFF"
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => AwesomeProject);
```

I am getting a weird error saying both `state.cameraType` is undefined and `this.refs` is undefined. I have a hunch that something is not getting bound and my `this` is not pointing to right thing but I have tried using both arrow functions and explicitly binding. See comment below. Anyway, I am not sure why it's acting up, any ideas?

Very similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34649020/undefined-is-not-an-object-this-state-not-getting-bound) except I have tried both the proposed solutions so I feel like something else is missing or I'm doing the binding wrong.

edit: Is there reason to be downvoted? Am I not being clear on something :o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out manual binding is the way to go, just needed to reload the app. I did not have hot-swapping enabled. Alternatively, arrow functions should also work.

Another thing to point out, for iOS 10 and above, you'll have to set 2 things in the `Info.plist` file, `Privacy - Camera Usage Description` and `Privacy - Photo Library Usage`. It can be any string value.